# How to create a saving file with a specific image in java?

Tags: java

I'm writing a java program and I need to create a save file with an extension invented by me and the file should also have an image chosen by me. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

Comment: when you say "image" what do you mean?

Comment: for example, when in Photoshop (or others) except a project, the save file has the symbol of Photoshop as an icon: I mean that.

Comment: You need to configure your OS to associate an icon to a file extension. Java can't do that by itself.

Comment: Ok so it must store binary data.  Have you tried using Java serialization?

Comment: would you please direct me to a link explaining how to do this?

Comment: initially I wanted to use it but serialization in my opinion is too dangerous, as you just need to change a line of code in the class and you can't read the contents of the serialized file before

Comment: Do you want to create the file with own icon image?

Comment: yes I wont create a file with own icon image

Answer (score 0):

> How can i assign icon for my custom file extension?

It's a system behaviour you can't alter this unless you change the registery in your machine.

to achive this you need to modify the registery in the deployed system (google for this you'll find links)

you need use RegOpenKeyEx(), RegGetValue(), RegSetKeyValue(), and don't forget to RegCloseKey()

Here's a link to the reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724875(VS.85).aspx

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT/

this call to `SHChangeNotify` this tell explorer to refresh the icon whenever it changes.